# Combine 2 cells with 2nd cell to be wrapped in brackets - Google Sheets / Apps Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to combine 2 cells of data - however the 2nd cell needs to be wrapped in brackets.

example - A2 has A11789 & B2 has 36. Join them in C2 so it looks like this **A11789(36)**

played around with the TextJoin but no luck

Apreciate any help on this

Thanks

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, for example, how about putting `=A2&"("&B2&")"` to the cell "C3"? Is this the direction you expect?

Comment: Tanaike - result in C2 - not C3

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: By the way, although this might not be good, when you use `TEXTJOIN` for the cells "A2:B2", I think that `=TEXTJOIN("(",TRUE,A2:B2)&")"` returns the same result. When you might obtain something from these sample formulas, I'm glad.

Comment: *played around with the TextJoin but no luck* For future reference, Explicitly document  the formula you've tested and the error you got, if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that in cell **C2**:

```
=CONCATENATE(A2,"(",B2,")")
```

[image]

In this way you concatenate A2, B2 and the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

You can use : `=A2&"("&B2&")"`

[image]